# How to load translations from multiple files and folders in Laravel in the boot method of a service provider?

Tags: php, laravel, translation

**Goal**
Load translations from multiple files in different directories.

**Description**
Inside the ServiceProvider of my Laravel package I can load all translations from one directory like this and it works:

```
public function boot()
{
   $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/lang', 'package-namespace');
}
```

The structure of the package is:

```
- config
- database
- resources
  - assets
  - lang
   - langA
   - langB
  - views
- routes
- src
  - moduleFolderA
    - Business
    - Controller
    - Routes
  - moduleFolderB
    - Business
    - Controller
    - Routes
  - moduleFolderC
    - Business
    - Controller
    - Routes
  - ServiceProvider.php
```

I want to split the translations for a more OOP approach and want to have a translation folder in every module folder. Inside the module folder is the logic of the package.

```
- moduleFolderA
  - Business
  - Controller
  - Routes
  - Translations
    - langA
       translationFileA.php
    - langB
       translationFileA.php
- moduleFolderB
  - Business
  - Controller
  - Routes
  - Translations
    - langA
       translationFileB.php
    - langB
       translationFileB.php
```

Inside the boot method of the ServiceProvider I tried things like

```
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/**/Translations/') as $path) {
            $this->loadTranslationsFrom($path, 'package-namespace');
        }
```

or

```
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/**/Translations/') as $path) {
           Lang::addNamespace('package-namespace', $path);;
        }
```

**Problem**
Only the last translation file of the iteration is available.

What could be a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you really want a better OOP approach I would recommend to build actual packages each having its own translation strings and then registering each package correctly with a service provider. Take a look at [package development](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#translations)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Inside the folders are the logic for the package. I update my description to clarify it.

Comment: My personal suggestion would be to make the translation files publisheable, so that users can publish it to laravels lang folder and edit it however they wish

Comment: @ArunAS yes of course the translations should be publishable so that users can modify them. But thats not my point. I talk about the structure inside the package. I would prefer to have the translations in the same folder as the logic for an operation. To me that seems more maintainable and more clear. It should make the coding and the maintenance on the package itself easier.

Comment: @leonp5, what I meant is that once the language files are published to the resources/lang folder, they are loaded automatically. You can place the translations in any folder of your package, and when publishing just send them all to lang folder. If you make publishing the language files compulsory, then the problem of needing to load them from different folders is solved. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#overriding-package-language-files. This doesn't solve your current problem, but is just an alternative approach. It's more of a temporary solution until you find a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppServiceProvider.php` file go to the `register` method then add this
`$this->app->bind('path.lang', function() { return base_path().'/vendor/package-name/resources/lang'; });`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but did you understand my question? My problem is **not** to load the translations from the standard directory in `resources/lang`. I want to split the translations in multiple files for a more OOP approach and load them from different paths.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and This is what I came up with.
**Folder structure**

```
Module
 - CustomModule
  - Resources
   - lang
     en.json (default lang files)
     fr.json
     - receipt
       en.json
       fr.json
```

In my module service provider I've added this in **registerTranslation** function

```
$this->loadJsonTranslationsFrom(module_path('CustomModule', 'Resources/lang/'));
$this->loadJsonTranslationsFrom(module_path('CustomModule', 'Resources/lang/receipt'));
```